# SQL query PDO Exception SQLSTATE[42000] ODBC driver

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc

Before I start to explain the problem and why I am here, exact message on exception is following:

```
PDOException in file.php line 615:
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Query Debug Log

```
PDO->query(' INSERT INTO #temp (ids) VALUES (167262241),(166467150),(166466679),(166465288),(167262561),(177607822)') in file.php line 615
```

as you can see that query is

```
INSERT INTO #temp (ids) VALUES (167262241),(166467150),(166466679),(166465288),(167262561),(177607822)
```

which has no problem in syntax and if I run this query directly on SQL server it gives me no exception and runs fine. But I am blank now why PHP PDO is throwing error.

Comment: For some reason I thought pdo didn't work with SQL Server

Comment: No, it does work but you need proper drivers and PDO extensions for SQL server.

Comment: Cool, what version operating system, web server, and php are you running?

Comment: PHP 5.5 , Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) , Apache 2.4, OS: Windows server 2012 R2

Comment: I am able to insert in temp table records one by one in a loop (Obviously it's not a good practice if I have 10000 records). I am trying to insert them in batches of 100. Is there another way to do that ?

Comment: Can you post the complete query (of the 100 ids you are trying to insert)?

Comment: yes sure I can post that query

Comment: still waiting for the full query to be posted, but if I had to guess, then I'd say you have an extra trailing comma dangling off the end of the statement that wasn't trimmed after a dynamic appending operation.